# Solving ODE with Laplace, with product of two functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How would I attack the following problem in order to solve it with Laplace transforms?

$$y'''-y=-ye^{2t},\quad y(0)=0,\quad y'(0)=-1,\quad y''(0)=-3.$$

My issue is that I'm not sure how to apply the Laplace transform when there is a product of two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's good news, and there's bad news. The good news is that
$$L\left[-ye^{2t}\right]=-Y(s-2).$$
But that's also the bad news, because now your DE becomes
$$s^3 Y(s)+s+3-Y(s)=-Y(s-2).$$
This is now a recurrence relation with no particularly easy solution in sight.  If you just run the following in Mathematica:

```
DSolve[{y'''[t]-y[t]==-y[t] Exp[2t],y[0]==0,y'[0]==-1,y''[0]==-3},y[t],t]
```

you get an immensely complicated expression involving `HypergeometricPFQ`. You can simplify it a bit if you run `//N` at the end of the `DSolve` command, but that produces an approximation. The result Mathematica yields has real and imaginary parts.

So you can solve this in terms of the `HypergeometricPFQ` function and the exponential; it's extremely complicated.